# downsides to submitting beta release to appstore for code review?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

is there any downside to submitting a beta version of my application to the appstore, for a version that I have no intention of releasing? main motivation is it's a lot of code, and I want to see if it will pass code review or if there are issues.

EDIT: I want to be clear that I am not asking this because I expect apple to do any level of testing/QA or anything like that, I have been through the app review process before. what I want to determine is if my application will pass the review process so that, when I am ready to release the "real" version, there is a smaller chance of it getting rejected for something that I could potentially address now.

I hope this is appropriate for stackoverflow, as I realize it's not strictly a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this, and there doesn't appear to have been any downsides. gained some confidence that subsequent submissions were more likely to be approved, and could estimate dates a bit better because of that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean code review? Apple does not see your code, they only see the application executable. I would not submit your application unless it's the final version. If you want someone to test your app, I recommend finding some friends or family members to test it for you.

EDIT: I still wouldn't submit your app just to see if it's "acceptable." Just read the [App review guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) and make sure you don't violate any of those and you should be fine.

Comment: sorry, I meant application review. I didn't want to do it for testing, I wanted to see if there was anything apple would reject it outright for, so I could fix it in advance, and hopefully minimize iterations once I'm ready to go live.

Answer (score 0):

We had a meeting with Apple last year about the exact same question, regarding a big banking app that the bank wanted approved before release. The clear answer was that Apple does not provide any testing services. They advise, as you'd expect, for you do your own QA testing, or hire a professional testing company.

Then when the app is ready for sale, make sure you read the the [App review guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) as **edc1591** suggested, make sure your app conforms to the guidelines, and only then submitted.

Comment: I've edited my question to try and make it more clear. I don't want or expect any testing/QA from apple, what I am hoping to get a sense of is if there is anything about my app they would reject me for, that I could then try and address. it's really more of a "setting client expectations about time to market" question. I am very aware that this is highly variable, I'm just trying to minimize chance of rejection to whatever extent I can.